# Opening Skype from java

Tags: java, skype

I am implementing a system for touchscreens in java that needs to be able to call up skype, how can I go from a fullscreen java app to having skype open, then closing the skype window and getting back to the fullscreen app. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Skype is installed, you can use the callto:// or skype:// protocol to start skype.

The syntax is

```
skype:<username|phonenumber>[?[add|call|chat|sendfile|userinfo]]
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: Do you mean from like Desktop.Open(call);  where call is a new file with a URI pointing to this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Could you include an example of a call to the test user echo123?

Comment: I tried skype:echo123 but it only works in the run command, how can I call this from java?

Comment: try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", "skype:echo123"});
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

Comment: @dah i am not getting profile information using this above syntax,plz help me

Comment: you need to be on windows xp

Comment: you also need to replace echo123 with your userid

Answer (score 2):

If it's a touchscreen system then why do you want to show the standard Skype UI? It's not a touch-compatible  interface. Have you considered using the Skype API to interact with the service instead?

There's a desktop automation library already available and a service SDK in beta.

http://developer.skype.com/

Comment: Looks like touch compatible to me. I don't want them to be able to do anything but click on a person in the list and then click call. The call button is fairly large and so is the box containing the user's name.

Comment: the SDK doesn't appear to be Java friendly.  No?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will have to implement a native library which will have to search through all windows in the system, find the Skype one and bring it to front. So it is possible, but with the help of native library -- which then you can still use in Java through JNI.