# Programmatically control Skype or Google+ client to initiate a video call

Tags: java, python, skype, skype4py, skype4java

Is there a way to write a program in Python, C/C++, or Java, or even web programming to initiate a Skype/Google+ Hangout Video Call to someone in your contacts list? (i.e. I want to programatically launch a Skype video call)

Has anyone done this before or know any examples where I can get started on this?

Thanks,

Comment: What would be the use for this? The only reason I can think of is turning on an unknowing friend's camera for bad purposes. Interesting question regardless.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish video streaming because I've tried setting up my own streaming server but it seemed to be kinda of laggy and sound does not go through.

Comment: Check if the Solution [in this REPLY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995003/1060037) works for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Skype from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993926/opening-skype-from-java)

Comment: You could script this using Skype4Py Python API https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer [URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

You can either use `callto:` or `skype:` to launch skype and call a particular number. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with using URI Schemes. Would I launch an http request and instead of http, place "skype:_____" within the blank?

Comment: @d.mc2 In Java, you would want to use a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).  The best approach would be to subclass it as a `SkypeURLConnection` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3):

From [Skype API reference](http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/reference#uriCallVideoExplicit):

```
skype:participant1[;participant2;...participant9]?call&video=true
```